# Is it correct and natural to say "be at the delivery" meaning to arrive at the delivery point?

Tags: word-choice, collocations

Would you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *be at the delivery* meaning to arrive at the delivery point? For example:

> The driver is already **at the delivery**, so we can go unload the truck.

If it's not natural, would you tell me if *at the delivery point* or *at the delivery site* would sound better?

Comment: Definitely 'the delivery site/point/address'. _At the delivery_ makers it sound like childbirth!

Comment: I'm fine with "at the delivery". It means the place where the delivery should happen. Might be a cross-pondial difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard this exact phrase used by delivery men.  Its a casual shortening of the longer phrase used in a context where the meaning is clear.  More formally, it would not be correct, and without the surrounding context (that the listener knows there is a delivery scheduled for some specific, known location, and the listener knows that the speaker is the one who is making the delivery) it would not be correct.